pdfkit breaks the file if process.exit is call after doc.end()
This is something I can't understand and I would like to ask you all, giving this code:
async function processCodes() {

 const doc = new PDFDocument();
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`ordine_${ordine}.pdf`));


for (const code of codesToPrint) {
    
    const qrCodeData = QRCode.toDataURL(code.code);

    if (y + qrCodeHeight > pageHeight) {
        doc.addPage();
        y = 0;  // Reset y position for the new page
    }

    // Add QR Code and text to the PDF
    doc.image(qrCodeData, 50, y, { fit: [150, 150] });  
    doc.text(code.code, 220, y + 50, { width: 400 });  
    
 
    y += qrCodeHeight + spacing;  // Increment y position
}

doc.end();
console.log('PDF generated!');
}

If i call this function like this:
processCodes().catch(err => console.error(err))

All good, everything works and i see the pdf.
If instead i use:
processCodes().catch(err => console.error(err)).finally(()=>process.exit(0))

The pdf i obtain is broken and can't be open.
Any Ideas?
Im asking out of curiosity since make no sense to me
